# タグの提案: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows用のタグ

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ

[Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (linux subsystem)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) 用のタグがあっても良いなと思いました。

[wsl](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl)をメインのタグにし、[bash-on-windows](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash-on-windows)、[windows-linux-subsystem](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-linux-subsystem)などをタグシノニムにするのはいかがでしょうか？

以下参考情報です：

- Stack Overflowでは[wsl](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl)です。 [windows-bash](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash)と[ubuntu-on-windows](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows)がタグシノニムになっています([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wsl/synonyms))。
- Superuserでは[windows-linux-subsystem](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-linux-subsystem)です。[linux-subsystem-windows](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-subsystem-windows)と[windows-subsystem-linux](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-linux)がタグシノニムになっています([参考](https://superuser.com/tags/windows-linux-subsystem/synonyms))。
- スタック・オーバーフローでは、たとえば以下の質問が該当すると考えられます。

  - [「bash on Windows は posix 互換ですか？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27800/bash-on-windows-%E3%81%AF-posix-%E4%BA%92%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)
  - [「anaconda3 on bash on windows で import matplotlib.pyplot するとエラーになる」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30612/anaconda3-on-bash-on-windows-%E3%81%A7-import-matplotlib-pyplot-%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B)
  - [「Bash on Windowsのダウンロードエラー(0x800703ee)」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33051/bash-on-windows%E3%81%AE%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC0x800703ee)
- 日本語だと「bash on Windows」でWSLを指していることがしばしばありますが、bashエミュレータの意味ではwindows7まででも "bash" がWindowsの上で動いていたためか、英語では「Bash on Ubuntu on Windows」の方が使われている気がします(要出典)。実際に[Stack Overflowで検索して見ても](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=bash%20on%20windows%20%5Bwsl%5D)、あまりこの用法は出てきません。

Comment: +1: Stack Overflow で wsl がメインタグになった経緯はこのあたりでしょうか http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326452/2818869

Answer (score 5, accepted):

質問で挙げられた3投稿について [wsl](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl) タグを設定した上で、より普及していると思われる Bash というキーワードからもこのタグにたどり着けるよう、次のようにしました。

- [bash-on-windows](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash-on-windows) → [wsl](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl) のシノニム設定
- [wsl](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl) の説明で Bash on Windows という表記にも言及

その他のシノニムについては必要そうなら別途作成する、という形でよいかと思います。